# How to resolve the following error in django UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.' .format(option))?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

While making migrations I'm getting the following errors in django

```
 raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'
.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: EADDRESS not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default va
lue.
```

[image]

Comment: I would follow the error suggestion and define address as an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

In .env

```
...
EADDRESS=your_address
```

In settings.py

```
...
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {} environment variable".format(var_name)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

EADDRESS = get_env_variable("EADDRESS")
```